# How to create an internal web form/application to gather user input and store it

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, forms

I work for a company in a department where I have been asked to create a form or document that managers can go into to submit team changes for an employee. employees can support different teams month over month within the business. my goal is to build a form or application in which managers can go in, choose an employee from a given list and select a team name, as well as an effective date of the change. my question is what can i use to build such a tool where i can gather data input and also have it stored somewhere for my reference. the current limitations are that we don't have our own SQL server and because it is a large bank i don't see us being able to create a web page or anything. Any advice?

Comment: Have you looked at SQLite?

Comment: no what is that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot to unpack from your question.  I've created several apps with forms for CRUD using Flask with SQLite. SQLite is a free and simple one file database with very low maintenance overhead.  Flask is a dead simple to get started yet has many specific packages available to create sophisticated apps.  Tons of documentation and support on the web and youtube.  You can create a prototype on your own machine then use an internal Linux server or better yet, a cloud provider like pythonanywhere.com or digitalocean.com once you want to share your app with others in your company.  I strongly encourage anyone taking this path to learn how to use virtual environment and git/GitHub before getting started.